# Continuous audio broadcast from ftp folder

Tags: javascript, php, audio, ftp

I have an internet radio on my webpage and I am streaming audio from my computer using as server w/o icecast/shoutcast.

But I can't spare time for this recently and I decided to upload some mp3 to my website's ftp folder.
I can retrive the mp3 folder files by php, parsing them to js and using a .onended method to play next song in a html5 audio element.

The problem is (actually it is not a problem, it is the natural behaviour) whenever the visitor hits the play button, the player begins to play from the first file in the js playlist array and skipping to next file until the whole array finishes.

This is a problem for me because what I want is still a broadcast in radio mentality. You know, you don't hit the play button when you turn on your radio. There is a song always playing there... So I decided to do something like that:

I found some php codes calculating mp3 duration by comparing it's size and bitrate. My plan is to calculate the total duration of all mp3s, then check the first file's upload time and substract it from now() to find eplased time, then figure out after how many mp3 and how many second the eplased time will be caught and finally make the audio element continue from that mp3's that point.

Is this possible? Some code suggestion? Any better idea?

Comment: would shuffling the list and autoplaying be radio-like enough?

Comment: Even, no shuffling is needed. I'll prepare the songs in will-be-playing order. I think this will make the estimating calculations easier, too...

Comment: btw, good MP3 use VBR, which means you can't tell duration from filesize and bitrate, unless it uses ABR, which is rarer. CBR supports zero-bit silence, so don't expect broadcast quality disc jockeying from php...

Comment: Yes, actually I had already swerved from that.

Answer (score 0):

Here I came so far...

PHP:

```
<? php
$ii = 0; //some counter also needed in javascript array
$totalDuration = 0; //total duration of mp3s need to be passed
$str=' '; //some string needed for javascript array
$handleAudioMp3 = 'audio/mp3/'; //my mp3 directory. all mp3s encoded carefully in CBR
$fileMp3 = scandir($handleAudioMp3); //get the items alphabetically
  foreach ($fileMp3 as &$value) {
    if ((!in_array($value,array(".","..","...")))){ //if its not parent,etc
      $f = $handleAudioMp3.$value; //let's define our file
      if ($ii==0) { //if it's the first file
        $eplased = (time()-filemtime($f)); //time eplased until the creation of first file
      }
      $m = new mp3file($f); //mp3file class http://www.zedwood.com/article/php-calculate-duration-of-mp3
      $a = $m->get_metadata(); //get the meta data of file
      if (($totalDuration + $a[Length])<$eplased) { //if the total duration passed mp3s still below the eplased time
        $totalDuration += $a[Length]; //add the file's length attr to total passed duration
        $initialFile=$f; //initial file will be the last file below eplased time
        unset($a); //release $a
      } 
      else { //if total duration exceeds eplased time then build js playlist array
        $str=$str.'audioPlayList['.$ii.'] = "'.$f.'";'; //build string for js
        $ii++;
      }
      }
  }
//WHY?
$sec=($eplased-$totalDuration); //problematic line. it should be the time added to initial file but sometimes it's very inaccurate, even negavite... 
unset($f);
unset($m);
unset($ii);
unset($value);
unset($eplased);
unset($totalDuration);
closedir($handleAudioMp3); ?>
```

HTML:

```
       <audio autoplay 
       controls="controls" 
       id="html5AudioPlayer" 
       src="<?php echo $initialFile ?>"></audio> //start from this file
```

JS:

```
var audioPlayList = new Array();
<?php echo $str ?> //built array

//find the audio section
var html5Audio = document.getElementById('html5AudioPlayer');

var i=0;
//attach event - on end - move to next one
 html5Audio.onended = function(){
 html5Audio.src = audioPlayList[i];
 i+=1
}
var ii = <?php echo $sec ?>; //seconds to continue
//attach event - play - to notify others
html5Audio.addEventListener('play', function () {
this.currentTime = ii;
ii=0; //play all files from 0 after all
 });
```

But still needs improving. There is an error in calculation of leap time. Helps will be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, one idea is to keep a server side cookie per playlist session tracking all these data. I mean, to create it once and get rid of all this heavy server side duty especially when the count of files is in hundereds.